# How to get an email with log details when errors occur with Slim and Monolog

Tags: php, slim, monolog, slim-3

My website is built over Slim Framework V3, and uses Monolog. I want to get an email notification when something goes wrong on my website (any log message above Error). In other words, I want to know when a Critical, Alert or Emergency message is logged.

Ideally, I want to also get the logs right before the error also in the same email, to make it easier to debug.

This is my current Monolog configuration (Slim default):

```
// monolog
$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    /** @var \Slim\Container $c */
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());

    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], $settings['level']));

    return $logger;
}
```

These are the log settings:

```
return [
    // Monolog settings
    'logger' => [
        'name' => 'slim-app',
        'path' => __DIR__ . '/logs/' . $logDate->format('Y-m-d') . '_app.log', //TODO: Make sure logs are above DocumentRoot
        'level' => \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG,
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution which involves the standard `StreamHandler`, the `NativeMailHandler` and the `FingersCrossedHandler`.

The `StreamHandler` simply logs everything above the given level, which is fine.

Now, the trick to get detailed emails when a certain level of error happens is to combine a `NativeMailHandler` with a `FingersCrossedHandler`.

```
// monolog
$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    /** @var \Slim\Container $c */
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());

    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], $settings['level']));

    //Handler to send email on critical (or above) errors
    //Uses the FingersCrossed strategy which buffers all messages preceeding the critical error
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $mailHandler = new Monolog\Handler\NativeMailerHandler(
        'me@example.com', //TODO: The email address where to send emails
        '[ERROR] : Unexpected error happened that requires immediate attention ' . $dt->format('Y-m-d'),
        'no-reply@example.com',
        $settings['level'],
        true,
        2000
    );
    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler($mailHandler, Monolog\Logger::CRITICAL));

    return $logger;
};
```

These are my logger settings (in settings.php):

```
return [
    // Monolog settings
    'logger' => [
        'name' => 'slim-app',
        'path' => __DIR__ . '/logs/' . $logDate->format('Y-m-d') . '_app.log', //TODO: Make sure logs are above DocumentRoot
        'level' => \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG,
    ]
];
```

**How it works**

According to the [monolog source code](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/FingersCrossedHandler.php), the `FingersCrossedHandler` does the following :

> Only requests which actually trigger an error (or whatever your
>   actionLevel is) will be in the logs, but they will contain all
>   records, not only those above the level threshold.

Therefore, this statement will make sure our NativeMailerHandler is used by the FingersCrossedHandler when a message with level Critical or more is called:

```
new Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler($mailHandler, Monolog\Logger::CRITICAL)
```

Hope this helps someone!